# Prevent .mouseout event from executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a listing of images and description in this HTML structure:

```
<div class="canDo">
    <p>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
        <span>Description 1</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
        <span>Description 2</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
        <span>Description 3</span>
    </p>

    <p></p>
</div>
```

I hide the `<span>` with CSS and add the description into the last `<p>` using a jQuery function. The HTML structure is chosen to work with my responsive layout as well.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(".canDo img").mouseover( function() {
        $(".canDo img").removeClass('active').addClass('fade');
        $(this).addClass('active').removeClass('fade');
        $(".canDo p:last-child").fadeOut(function() {
            var msg = $('.canDo img.active').next('span').html()
            $(".canDo p:last-child").text(msg).fadeIn();
        });
    })
    .mouseout( function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".canDo img").removeClass('active fade')
            $(".canDo p:last-child").fadeOut();
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```

The problem I'm having is that when I hover the first item and then the second item (and keep the mouse on that second one) the `mouseout` function from the first item is executed, making the fading effect and the text disappear.

How can I prevent that from happening?

I also made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/L9v5wqun/).

Comment: so.... if there's text in the lower box... and a new item is hover'd over.. do you want it to fade-out (w/ old), then fade-in (w/ new) or just pop up the new?

Comment: updated http://jsfiddle.net/bpd2Ldy1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this... I think it's what you want.  let me know if it's not.

http://jsfiddle.net/bpd2Ldy1/

so... what I did was assign the result of the `setTimeout` function (which returns a specific timeout id) to the variable `tm`.  If it is set (meaning something is fading out after 3 seconds), and the user mouses-over another little box, it will clear and stop the timeout.  that allows for it to not conflict with the new mouseover event.  if nothing `.canDo` is moused-over, the timeout will complete uninterrupted after 3 seconds.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(".canDo img").mouseover( function() {
        $(".canDo img").removeClass('active').addClass('fade');
        $(this).addClass('active').removeClass('fade');

        if (typeof(tm) != 'undefined') {
            clearTimeout(tm);
        }
        $(".canDo p:last-child").stop().fadeOut(function() {
            var msg = $('.canDo img.active').next('span').html()
            $(".canDo p:last-child").text(msg).stop().fadeIn();
        });

    })
    .mouseout( function() { 
        tm = window.setTimeout(function(){
            $(".canDo img").removeClass('active fade')
            $(".canDo p:last-child").stop().fadeOut("slow");  
        }, 3000); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I almost does what I want. What I'd like to add is that when I mouseout (completely out of the list) the text stays 3 sec and the fades out. Is that possible?

Comment: @LinkinTED ... yeah... if we can figure out the logic.  just the state the obvious (hopefully)... say 1 is selected, and they move to 2, you want the description for 1 to remain for 3 seconds before showing description 2...

Comment: No, that may swap direct. But when moving out of two into the document, *then* description 2 should disappear after 3 seconds.