# on drag change stylesheets for all dropzones (file upload)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple dropzones for uploading files on a webpage

How to highlight all dropzone elements as soon as a file is dragged into the browser, so the user knows where to drop the file? And when a file is dragged over one of the dropzones I need to add an additional class to indicate the user can release the file

## update

kurideja pointed me in the right direction to Dragster

https://github.com/bensmithett/dragster

Now it almost works :)

- If you drag over one dropzone and drag back out without releasing the file all dropzones are hidden

http://jsfiddle.net/L7v2f96z/9/

html

```
<div class="dropzone"></div>
<div class="dropzone"></div>
```

javascript

```
//    Add/remove class when file is dragged over the dropzone. Hover effect
$('.dropzone').dragster({
    enter : function(){
        $(this).show().addClass('hover');
    },
    leave : function(){
        $(this).hide().removeClass('hover');
    }
});

//    Show/hide dropzones until a file is dragged into the browser window. Hide dropzones after file is dropped or dragging is stopped
var w = $(window).dragster({
    enter : function(){
        $('.dropzone').show();
    },
    leave : function(){
        $('.dropzone').hide();
    }
})
//    Prevent defaults (file is openened in the browser) if user drops file outside a dropzone
.on('dragover', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
})
.on('drop', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    w.trigger('dragleave');
});
```

css

```
.dropzone {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:#fff;
    display:none;
    border:2px dashed rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow:0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), inset 0 0 40px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border-radius:2px;
    margin:10px;
}

.dropzone.hover {
    background:#e3e3e3;
}
```

Comment: Are you using JQuery UI? Im asking because the drag/drop functionality in the JQuery UI allows you to highlight a dropzone and im pretty sure you can rig it to allow more than one highlight on drop. http://jqueryui.com/droppable/

Comment: what part doesn't IE like?  the flicker might be caused by the timeout... you should probably assign it to a variable so you can cancel it if the user is still dragging stuff around but happened to trigger your `dragout` timer.  I did something similar in [this answer over here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26447749/623952) once upon a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Main problem was: after leaving the dropzone area, **dragster triggered `leave` twice**, both on `.dropzone` and `window`. Simply adding **e.stopPropagation()** solves the problem. There are also few more fixes (removed show() and hide() inside dropzone dragster). Your [code on Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L7v2f96z/10/) and also below:

```
// Add/remove class when file is dragged over the dropzone. Hover effect
$('.dropzone').dragster({
    enter: function() {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
    },
    leave: function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation(); //-- Critical point
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    }
});

// Show/hide dropzones until a file is dragged into the browser window. Hide dropzones after file is dropped or dragging is stopped
var w = $(window).dragster({
    enter: function() {
        $('.dropzone').show();
    },
    leave: function() {
        $('.dropzone').hide();
    }
})
// Prevent defaults (file is openened in the browser) if user drop file outside a dropzone
.on('dragover', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
})
    .on('drop', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    w.trigger('dragleave');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `e.originalEvent.pageX`and `e.originalEvent.pageY` on dragover and check if its in a range of the box. For this example I have copied the dropzone and I know the width and height of the div so I could hardcode the condition. You will have to come up with a way to store the position(top and left) of the dropzone areas and use that for comparison.

```
var drag_timer;
$(document).on('dragover', function (e) {
    var dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;

    if (dt.types && (dt.types.indexOf ? dt.types.indexOf('Files') != -1 : dt.types.contains('Files'))) {
        if (e.originalEvent.pageX <= 200 && e.originalEvent.pageY <= 200) {
            $('.dropzone').removeClass('highlight');
            $('.dropzone:eq(0)').addClass('highlight');
        } else if (e.originalEvent.pageX <= 400 && e.originalEvent.pageY <= 400) {
            $('.dropzone').removeClass('highlight');
            $('.dropzone:eq(1)').addClass('highlight');
        } else {
            $('.dropzone').removeClass('highlight');
        }

        $('.dropzone').show();
        window.clearTimeout(drag_timer);
    }
})
.on('dragleave', function (e) {
  drag_timer = window.setTimeout(function () {
    $('.dropzone').hide();
  }, 50);
});
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/ke0rsmvc/7/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `target` member of the event to get the proper element:

```
var drag_timer;
$(document).on('dragover', function(e){
    var dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
    if(dt.types && (dt.types.indexOf ? dt.types.indexOf('Files') != -1 : dt.types.contains('Files'))){
        $('.dropzone').show();
        window.clearTimeout(drag_timer);
    }
})
.on('dragleave', function(e){
    drag_timer = window.setTimeout(function(){
        $('.dropzone').hide();
    }, 50);
});

$('.dropzone')
.on('dragenter', function(e){
    $(e.originalEvent.target).addClass('highlight');
})
.on('dragleave', function(e){
    $(e.originalEvent.target).removeClass('highlight');
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mzcqxfq3/

Answer (score 1):

Some drag events are fired on EACH element, so basically there is not a one continuous drag, but a sequence of drags over all elements below the mouse.

Just use this plugin: http://javascript.hew.io/bensmithett/dragster

Comment: Nice plugin! :) Have created a jsfiddle.. Now my problem is that the dragster on document is only working until the first time you drag over a dropzone http://jsfiddle.net/L7v2f96z/2/

Comment: Have updated the question with an updated jsfiddle where Im not using the jquery version of dragster.. :)

Answer (score 1):

> In my case I wanted to change the style of the class the moment I put
>   a new file and when the dropzone was filled, I did the following:

```
.dz-drag-hover , .dz-started {        
        border: 2px solid #0CB598;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be very similar to your aproach.
When a file is draged into the window, add a css-class to the element which contains all drop-zones (body if neccessary). Then you can style your drop-zones on drag accordingly:

```
$(document).on('dragover', function(e){
    var dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
    if(dt.types && (dt.types.indexOf ? dt.types.indexOf('Files') != -1 : dt.types.contains('Files'))){
        $('body').addClass('dragging'); // Adding a class to the body
    }
})
.on('dragleave', function(e){
    $('body').removeClass('dragging')
});
```

The css would be:

```
/* style the drop-zone */
.dropzone {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    display:none;
    border:2px dashed black;
}

/* show the dropzone when file is dragged into window */
body.dragging .dropzone{
    display:block;
}

/* highlight box when hovered but only when file is dragged */
body.dragging .dropzone:hover{
    background:gray;
}
```

If this isn't what you wanted pleas tell me in a comment ;)

**EDIT**
Of course you have to remove the class when the file is droped

```
$(document).on('drop', function(event) {
    $('body').removeClass('dragging');
}
```

Comment: have created a jsfiddle.. but it doesn't seem to work http://jsfiddle.net/co53d9jf/

Comment: @clarkk jeah it seems the style from hover is just not applied when using drag. For me thats unexpected behaviour. I hope this will be fixed some day but for now it doenst help much...

Answer (score -1):

1. IE11 bug caused by `dt.types.indexOf`, `e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.types` is a DOMStringList object in ie.
   So you shoud use `dt.types.contains` instead of`dt.types.indexOf`.

The following works:

```js
var drag_timer;

$(document).on('dragover', function(e) {
  var dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
  if (dt.types != null &&
      (dt.types.indexOf ? dt.types.indexOf('Files') != -1 :
         (dt.types.contains('Files') ||
         dt.types.contains('application/x-moz-file')))) {
    $('.dropzone').show();
    window.clearTimeout(drag_timer);
  }
})
.on('dragleave', function(e) {
  drag_timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
    $('.dropzone').hide();
  }, 25);
});
```

```css
.dropzone {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropzone"></div>
```

Comment: I found out that this line both works in chrome, ie and firefox.. `if(dt.types && (dt.types.indexOf ? dt.types.indexOf('Files') != -1 : dt.types.contains('Files'))){` ... `dt.types[0]` doesn't make sense since `dt.types` is an array or domstringlist and if you use `dt.types[0]` you only search the first item of the array/domstringlist

Comment: I got a better solution & update my answer. IE should use `dt.types.contains` to check type, just like FF.

Comment: Thats also what I wrote in the first comment :)